# TMUX setting environment variables for sessions

Tags: tmux

I work in a situation where I have multiple projects and within each are many scripts that make use of environment variables set to values specific to that project.

What i'd like to do is use a separate tmux session for each project and set the variables so that they are set for all windows in that session.

I tried to use the set-environment option which works using the -g option but then sets the variable for all sessions connected to that server.

Without the -g option I see its set when using show-environment but can't access the variable in the shell.

Has anyone come up with a way of fixing this?

Using tmux 1.8 and tcsh

Answer (score 27):

I figured out a way to do this. I'm using tmux 2.5.

**Background**

In the tmux man page, it states that there are two groups of environment variables: global and per-session. When you create a new tmux session, it will merge the two groups together and that becomes the set of environment variables available within the session. If the environment variables get added to the global group, it appears that they get shared between all open sessions. You want to add them to the per-session group.

**Do this**

Step 1: Create a tmux session.

```
tmux new-session -s one
```

Step 2: Add an environment variable to the per-session group.

```
tmux setenv FOO foo-one
```

This adds the environment variable to per-session set of environment variables. If you type `tmux showenv`, you'll see it in the output. However, it isn't in the environment of the current session. Typing `echo $FOO` won't give you anything. There's probably a better way to do this, but I found it easiest to just export it manually:

```
export FOO='foo-one'
```

Step 3: Create new windows/panes

Now, every time you create a new window or pane in the current session, tmux will grab the FOO environment variable from the per-session group.

**Automating it**

I use bash scripts to automatically create tmux sessions that make use of these environment variables. Here's an example of how I might automate the above:

```
#!/bin/bash
BAR='foo-one'
tmux new-session -s one \; \
  setenv FOO $BAR \; \
  send-keys -t 0 "export FOO="$BAR C-m \; \
  split-window -v \; \
  send-keys -t 0 'echo $FOO' C-m \; \
  send-keys -t 1 'echo $FOO' C-m
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `setenv`, exactly, if the environment variables set via that command cannot be accessed by something like `echo $foo`?

Comment: When you create a session, it creates window 0 automatically, which fires off a shell. So, for that shell, setenv doesn't work and you have to send-keys. But when you create a new window, like with split-window, the new window gets the environment from the setenv. The example shows that both windows have the environment whether set explicitly via export or via setenv.

Comment: Why It does not work for multiple `setenv`: `sentenv FOO $BAR \; \ setenv FIZZ $BUZZ` ?

Comment: Nowadays `tmux new-session -s SESSION_NAME -e VAR=VALUE` is supported, you can specify `-e` multiple times to define multiple environment variables for a specific session. See [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html) and check the `new-session` command.

Answer (score 14):

You can access tmux (local) environment variables for each session, while in a session, with the command:

```
bash> tmux show-environment
```

If you add the -g parameter you get the environment for all sessions, i.e. the global environment. The local environments are NOT the same as the global environment. The previous command prints the entire local environment, but you can also look at just one variable:

```
bash> tmux show-environment variable_name
          variable_name=value
```

To get the value, you could use some 'sed' magic or use 'export' on a single variable, or you can even 'export' the entire environment to your shell. Below are the 3 approaches.

```
bash> tmux show-environment variable_name | sed "s:^.*=::"
         value

bash> eval "export $(tmux show-environment variable_name)"
bash> echo $variable_name
         value    

bash> for var in $(tmux show-environment | grep -v "^-"); do eval "export $var"; done;
bash> echo $variable_name
         value
```

If needed, you can just add the -g parameter after the show-environment command if you want to access the global environment.

Answer (score 7):

I've done a simple

```
export MY_VAR="some value"
```

before I start the tmux session, which gives me access to `MY_VAR` from all windows inside that session.

Comment: what about doing this every time when you start tmux?

Comment: @holms For this you could
`alias tmux='SOME_ENV_VAR=somevalue tmux'`

Comment: This works when you create your first session and `tmux` starts up its server process. But if you start a second session, that will connect to the same tmux server, so it will get the environment variables that were set when you first started the server, not the most recent ones.

Comment: It affects all the sessions connected to the server. All newly created windows will be also affected...

Comment: @ghchoi but if you have other tmux-sessions connected to that server already running, exporting the variable before opening another session doesn't work

Answer (score 6):

Version 3.2 of tmux will support a `-e` option for the `new-session` command for altering the local environment directly.

In the mean time, you can use this to run a new tmux session with a particular environment available and up to date (or one of the other solutions mentioned):

```
tmux new-session 'export MY_VAR=value; exec bash'
```

The problem with tmux is that when you first run it, the tmux server is created and it inherits the environment that is available at this time of creation. This is called the global environment. When you run tmux again and create a new session, the tmux server still holds its copy of the environment. But this copy is the "old" environment that the server learned about when it was created, i.e. the global environment.

About the tmux commands that work with the tmux environment:

- `set update-environment MY_VAR`: this will tell tmux to take the `MY_VAR` variable from the global environment and make it a session environment, i.e. a local environment (listed by the `show-environment` command). Then, the session will be able to change the value of this variable without affecting the global environment.
- `set-environment MY_VAR value`: This will create (or change) a variable in the local environment of the session.
- `set-environment -g MY_VAR value`: This will create (or change) a variable in the global environment.

Also, note that when you run tmux and tmux calls bash (or another shell), bash will have a copy of the server's (global) environment. Even if you change an environment variable before calling tmux, creating a new session will be oblivious of the changes. If you add a tmux command in a conf file and run tmux e.g. with `tmux source-file tmux-session.conf`, any variable you mention in the conf will be evaluated in the context of the global environments the tmux server knows about and not the in the context from where you run the tmux command. So, in order to make a new session see the new value of the variable, you have to call tmux in a way that passes the new value of the env variable directly to it. This is what the solutions here try to do. This is also what the new `-e` option will allow you to do.

Answer (score 3):

I approached this a little differently, assuming I had separate initialization scripts for each environment.

Using tmux v3.0a.

### The spec:

1. When I invoke `tmux` I want it to load up a specific environment for that session.
2. For each window within the tmux session I want that same environment session replicated.
3. I also want to be able to invoke subsequent `tmux` sessions with different environments and each window invocation should load that environment. (just like the first session)  And subsequent sessions should not interfere with prior sessions.
4. I have shell scripts to initialize each of my environments.

So how can I associate a shell script with a session and have all window invocations use that shell script?

### Simple Solution:

Found a simple solution here: [How to start two tmux sessions with different environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506708/how-to-start-two-tmux-sessions-with-different-environments)

With my original solution I ran into an issue with the tmux global environment.  When I ran multiple sessions, whichever one ran first set the global environment.  Then I would need to close other tmux sessions before I ran new sessions.

A better solution is to set up a separate tmux server for each environment.

Use the `-L` flag to tmux from within a shell that already has the environment defined you want.

Shell environment A: `tmux -L environA`

Shell environment B: `tmux -L environB`

Name your environments any way you want.  Set up some aliases for each environment?  Or you can test environment variables to determine which tmux server you want to use.  Each tmux named server will keep its environment separate.

Then there is no need to set bash startup files, etc. as I had described in my original solution.

Comment: This answer had the key missing bit I needed: I had multiple sessions, and isolated them using unique `-L <name>` args solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

## Example

In my case I'm starting a `tmux` session per project within a bash script and I needed to activate a relevant virtual environment for that session, including any newly opened tabs. To do so, I added the following virtual environment activation code to the `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
if [ -n "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]; then
    source $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate;
fi
```

However if I need to set `foo` environment for `Session_1` and `bar` environment for `Session_2`, the `VIRTUAL_ENV` variable is globally set to `bar` after creating `Session_2`, so any newly opened tabs in `Session_1` erroneously ends up in `bar` environment.

## Solution

> [original HOWTO](https://github.com/aktos-io/scada.js/blob/master/doc/using-virtual-environment.md#preparing-tmux) ([`commit`](https://github.com/aktos-io/scada.js/blob/e3e8dbcd895eae213b4009bec74afc70d2246141/doc/using-virtual-environment.md#preparing-tmux)).

1. Add the following in your `~/.profile` (or `~/.bashrc`):

```sh
# For Tmux VirtualEnv support
tmux_get_var(){
    local key=$1
    [[ -n "$TMUX" ]] && tmux showenv | awk -F= -v key="$key" '$1==key {print $2}'
}

# activate the virtual environment if it is declared
venv=$(tmux_get_var "VIRTUAL_ENV")
if [ -n "$venv" ]; then
    source $venv/bin/activate;
fi
```

2. Set the `VIRTUAL_ENV` variable for the target session:

```sh
tmux setenv -t ${SESSION_NAME} 'VIRTUAL_ENV' /path/to/virtualenv/
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting it for current *session* is quite easy: <kbd>Ctr-b</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> to open *tmux* command prompt and enter `setenv FOO foo`. This will not apply for existing *windows* -- but there you can use `export $(tmux show-env FOO)`.

For new sessions this pattern might be useful:

1. `tmux new -s session`
2. <kbd>Ctr-b</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> `set-env FOO foo` -- set `FOO=foo` for the session
3. <kbd>Ctr-b</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> -- create new, second window (`$FOO` is set here)
4. <kbd>Ctr-b</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> -- go to old, first window
5. `exit` the first window
6. all windows now have `FOO=foo`

Tested with Tmux 1.8.